# Render whole page as JSON content instead of HTML with Nuxt.js

Tags: json, vue.js, nuxt.js

Currently my Nuxt.js application serves HTML pages defined in layouts, pages, routes and components.

Is it possible to render one single route / one page as a standard JSON Response? Is that possible? I mean do not render the HTML e.g. Tags - only pure JSON!

What I already tried:

- Created a completely clean layout (with basically only  in it), no succcess, still HTML.
- Used `<pre>{{jsonObject}}</pre>` hoping to get plain JSON, no success.

Would be VERY happy, if somebody could tell me whether this is possible AT ALL or not?

Comment: not possible, you should use either a static file or make an API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for here, is an API.

Vue.js will render a template (compiled to render functions, generating a DOM tree) at the end, because it's aimed towards a frontend usage. If you want to render something like an API response with pure JSON, you need to look into [Express](https://expressjs.com/) or alike.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I do understand that. Of course, I could host an API/endpoints somehow else, yes. The motivation of my question was: Is it possible to integrate Express into my current Nuxt application anyways? Somehow at routing level inside Nuxt? So Nuxt serves all the frontend routes and serves/pipes the request for just ONE single route (which access Express in the background)? I do not want to setup a second project just for that one route AND I do need to process some logic (so I do not want to serve one single static file).

Comment: Nuxt can have a middleware baked into Express as metioned here: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/discussions/9203#discussioncomment-666044 Here is the related documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware/#the-servermiddleware-property @NetWurst